# How to define a conditional field for checkbox in DocuSign using REST APIs in Java?

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying to set conditional rule for checkbox, such that when the checkbox is "Checked", the document can be signed. I am able to do in the template in DocuSign(see  pic - [Setting the conditional rule on checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x8ZD.png))

When the checkbox is checked, the signature tab (and date-signed tab) will enable.

When I am trying to implement this in code, I am not able to set any conditional rule over the checkbox.

```
    SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
    signHere.setTabLabel("signHere");
    signHere.setDocumentId("1");
    signHere.setPageNumber("1");
    signHere.setXPosition("113");
    signHere.setYPosition("620");
    signHere.setConditionalParentLabel("checkbox");
    signHere.setConditionalParentValue("Checked");

    DateSigned dateSigned = new DateSigned();
    dateSigned.setDocumentId("1");
    dateSigned.setPageNumber("1");
    dateSigned.setXPosition("403");
    dateSigned.setYPosition("630");

    Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox();
    checkbox.setDocumentId("1");
    checkbox.setPageNumber("1");
    checkbox.setXPosition("130");
    checkbox.setYPosition("564");
    checkbox.setRequired("true");
    checkbox.setTabLabel("checkbox");
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A sample JSON code for this would be like below, I think you need to put conditionalParentValue to be `"on"` instead of `"checked"`

```
{
  "documents": [{
    "documentBase64": "<Base64>",
    "documentId": "12345",
    "fileExtension": "txt",
    "name": "f4506t"
  }],
  "emailBlurb": "Email Blurb",
  "emailSubject": "Email Subject",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
          {
            "email": "email@gmail.com",
            "name": "DS SSO",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
              "checkboxTabs": [{
                    "tabLabel": "Checkbox1",
                    "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                    "conditionalParentValue": null,
                    "pageNumber": 1,
                    "documentId": "12345",
                    "xPosition": 168,
                    "yPosition": 123
                }],
              "initialHereTabs": [
                {
                  "conditionalParentLabel": "Checkbox1",
                  "conditionalParentValue": "on",
                  "documentId": "12345",
                  "pageNumber": "1",
                  "tabLabel": "Initial1",
                  "xPosition": "300",
                  "yPosition": "500",
                  "optional": "true"
                }
              ],
              "signHereTabs": [
                {
                  "conditionalParentLabel": "Checkbox1",
                  "conditionalParentValue": "on",
                  "documentId": "12345",
                  "pageNumber": "1",
                  "tabLabel": "Sign1",
                  "xPosition": "500",
                  "yPosition": "400"
                }
              ],
              "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "Date Signed1",
                "conditionalParentLabel": "Checkbox1",
                "conditionalParentValue": "on",
                "pageNumber": 1,
                "documentId": "12345",
                "xPosition": 239,
                "yPosition": 198
            }]
            }
          }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
signHere.setConditionalParentValue("Checked");
```

to

```
signHere.setConditionalParentValue("on");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Required%20checkbox) of a required checkbox for an envelope. The example uses the [API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com) tool.

There's also a live example of [requiring one of multiple checkboxs](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Require%20one%20of%20multiple%20checkboxes)

The tool can output code for the DocuSign eSign API SDKs using C#, Java, PHP, Node.js, Python, and Ruby

Here's the JSON for one required checkbox

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign the attached document",
    "status": "sent",
    "documents": [
      {
        "filename": "anchorfields.pdf",
        "name": "Example document",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "1"
      }
    ],
    "recipients": {
      "signers": [
        {
          "email": "signer_email@example.com",
          "name": "Signer's name",
          "recipientId": "1",
          "clientUserId": "1000",
          "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                "anchorXOffset": "20",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
              }
            ],
            "checkboxTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                "anchorXOffset": "180",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabGroupLabels": [
                  "checkbox group"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "tabGroups": [
              {
                "groupLabel": "checkbox group",
                "groupRule": "SelectAtLeast",
                "minimumRequired": "1",
                "maximumAllowed": "1",
                "validationMessage": "Please check to indicate your agreement",
                "tabScope": "document",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "documentId": "1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```